# Alternatives for pyatogui's locateOnScreen()?

Tags: python, computer-vision, macros, ui-automation, pyautogui

I wrote and have been using a function that waits for a certain image to pop up on screen. It makes use of pyautogui's locateOnScreen. When the desired image shows up, the loop ends. I use the function for macros, whenever they wait for a loading to end or when to take the next step. Take a look.

```
def waitImage(image):
while pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, grayscale = True, confidence = 0.8) == None:
    time.sleep(.5)
```

However, this code is too demanding and my computer gets extremely hot from executing it for a little while. I was wondering if there is a simpler solution to this or code from other libraries that make this easier?

Comment: Do you really have no idea where on the screen the image will appear?  You can vastly speed up `locateOnScreen()` by adding a `region=(left, top, width, height)` parameter to limit how much of the screen needs to be searched.

Comment: Oh yes, I am aware of that. This function I posted doesn't have it, but I usually use the region parameter. That still is demanding on the computer.

Comment: what operating system? find a library that hooks into accessibility APIs (e.g. for the visually impaired) to directly retrieve the structure of whatever GUI you're looking for. -- does this `locateOnScreen` use opencv's `matchTemplate` or some other implementation? what resolution does your screen have? why not work on a low res version of the picture? can you quantify the time that one call takes?